iwlwifi: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0. - MSI Prestige 16 Evo
recently I changed laptop for work. Built-in with Windows I wanted to install Ubuntu instead. I tried the LTS version (22.04) and the most recent version (23.10).
The MSI prestige EVO 16 comes with this config:

disk: NVMe SSD Controller PM9A1/PM9A3/980PRO SAMSUNG MZVL21T0HDLU-00BT7
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) Ultra 7 155H
wifi: Intel(R) Killer(TM) Wi-Fi 7 BE1750

iwlwifi seems to crash and restart very often, causing freezes etc.
As far as I know, the firmware used is the last up to date.
I tried several things but to no avail. For example, I found a similar topic on arch
result of dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    2.577972] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.587694] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: Detected crf-id 0x2001910, cnv-id 0x2001910 wfpm id 0x80000000
[    2.587825] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: PCI dev 272b/1773, rev=0x472, rfid=0x112200
[    2.602321] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.602354] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.4.125
[    2.603013] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: loaded firmware version 83.ec13314b.0 gl-c0-fm-c0-83.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.948670] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: Detected Intel(R) TBD Bz device, REV=0x472
[    2.971440] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[    3.223241] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: loaded PNVM version 8443a58d
[    3.330278] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: base HW address: c8:8a:9a:c2:3d:d2
[    3.430358] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0 wlp85s0f0: renamed from wlan0
[  282.680691] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[  283.047383] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: Registered PHC clock: iwlwifi-PTP, with index: 1
[  475.840101] WARNING: CPU: 20 PID: 669 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/rx.c:1489 iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x3d0/0x630 [iwlwifi]
[  475.840312]  uvcvideo btbcm snd_seq_midi btintel videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_midi_event uvc btmtk videobuf2_memops drm_buddy videobuf2_v4l2 ttm snd_rawmidi bluetooth videodev iwlwifi hid_sensor_prox drm_display_helper snd_seq hid_sensor_als cmdlinepart hid_sensor_trigger mei_gsc_proxy spi_nor videobuf2_common industrialio_triggered_buffer pmt_telemetry cec processor_thermal_device_pci kfifo_buf snd_seq_device snd_timer hid_sensor_iio_common mtd pmt_class intel_rapl_msr ecdh_generic rc_core processor_thermal_device cfg80211 intel_cstate ecc mc industrialio snd msi_wmi wmi_bmof mei_me i2c_i801 spi_intel_pci processor_thermal_rfim processor_thermal_mbox i2c_smbus drm_kms_helper mei intel_vpu soundcore spi_intel processor_thermal_rapl i2c_algo_bit intel_vsec intel_rapl_common int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone gpio_keys int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel intel_hid acpi_tad soc_button_array acpi_pad sparse_keymap input_leds hid_multitouch mac_hid serio_raw msr parport_pc ppdev drm lp parport efi_pstore dmi_sysfs ip_tables
[  475.840508] CPU: 20 PID: 669 Comm: irq/197-iwlwifi Not tainted 6.5.0-26-generic #26-Ubuntu
[  475.840521] RIP: 0010:iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x3d0/0x630 [iwlwifi]
[  475.840630]  ? iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x3d0/0x630 [iwlwifi]
[  475.840681]  ? iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x3d0/0x630 [iwlwifi]
[  475.840706]  ? iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x3d0/0x630 [iwlwifi]
[  475.840736]  iwl_pcie_napi_poll_msix+0x32/0x100 [iwlwifi]
[  475.840795]  iwl_pcie_irq_rx_msix_handler+0xd7/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[  475.841441] WARNING: CPU: 20 PID: 669 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/rx.c:1489 iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x3d0/0x630 [iwlwifi]
[  475.841525] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[  475.841530]  snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec crypto_simd cryptd i915 rapl snd_hda_core libarc4 snd_hwdep snd_pcm btusb btrtl uvcvideo btbcm snd_seq_midi btintel videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_midi_event uvc btmtk videobuf2_memops drm_buddy videobuf2_v4l2 ttm snd_rawmidi bluetooth videodev iwlwifi hid_sensor_prox drm_display_helper snd_seq hid_sensor_als cmdlinepart hid_sensor_trigger mei_gsc_proxy spi_nor videobuf2_common industrialio_triggered_buffer pmt_telemetry cec processor_thermal_device_pci kfifo_buf snd_seq_device snd_timer hid_sensor_iio_common mtd pmt_class intel_rapl_msr ecdh_generic rc_core processor_thermal_device cfg80211 intel_cstate ecc mc industrialio snd msi_wmi wmi_bmof mei_me i2c_i801 spi_intel_pci processor_thermal_rfim processor_thermal_mbox i2c_smbus drm_kms_helper mei intel_vpu soundcore spi_intel processor_thermal_rapl i2c_algo_bit intel_vsec intel_rapl_common int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone gpio_keys int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel intel_hid acpi_tad soc_button_array acpi_pad sparse_keymap
[  475.841639] CPU: 20 PID: 669 Comm: irq/197-iwlwifi Tainted: G        W          6.5.0-26-generic #26-Ubuntu
[  475.841646] RIP: 0010:iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x3d0/0x630 [iwlwifi]
[  475.841709]  ? iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x3d0/0x630 [iwlwifi]
[  475.841753]  ? iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x3d0/0x630 [iwlwifi]
[  475.841773]  ? iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x3d0/0x630 [iwlwifi]
[  475.841797]  iwl_pcie_napi_poll_msix+0x32/0x100 [iwlwifi]
[  475.841807] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[  475.841813] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
[  475.841816] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 83.ec13314b.0 gl-c0-fm-c0-83.ucode
[  475.841818] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[  475.841821] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000EF3 | trm_hw_status0
[  475.841830] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[  475.841831] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x002C280A | branchlink2
[  475.841834] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x002BB0D0 | interruptlink1
[  475.841837] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x002BB0D0 | interruptlink2
[  475.841840] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00005C18 | data1
[  475.841843] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x01000000 | data2
[  475.841845] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[  475.841847] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0xCE0037D8 | beacon time
[  475.841850] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0xB1B167F6 | tsf low
[  475.841852] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x0000014D | tsf hi
[  475.841853] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[  475.841855] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x0B83206A | time gp2
[  475.841858] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[  475.841860] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000053 | uCode version major
[  475.841863] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0xEC13314B | uCode version minor
[  475.841865] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000472 | hw version
[  475.841867] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00C80002 | board version
[  475.841868] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x047E001C | hcmd
[  475.841873] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0xE6FA8000 | isr0
[  475.841874] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x01440000 | isr1
[  475.841877] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x48F0000A | isr2
[  475.841880] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00C0000F | isr3
[  475.841882] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x08000000 | isr4
[  475.841885] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x047E001C | last cmd Id
[  475.841886] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00005C18 | wait_event
[  475.841887] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x049400B4 | l2p_control
[  475.841889] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x0001BC34 | l2p_duration
[  475.841890] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x01000050 | l2p_mhvalid
[  475.841892] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000158 | l2p_addr_match
[  475.841893] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[  475.841894] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[  475.841884]  iwl_pcie_irq_rx_msix_handler+0xd7/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[  475.841896] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000860 | flow_handler
[  475.842164] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[  475.842167] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
[  475.842169] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 83.ec13314b.0 gl-c0-fm-c0-83.ucode
[  475.842170] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[  475.842172] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x000002F0 | trm_hw_status0
[  475.842173] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[  475.842174] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x002C280A | branchlink2
[  475.842176] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x002B79C6 | interruptlink1
[  475.842177] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x002B79C6 | interruptlink2
[  475.842178] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x002A50FC | data1
[  475.842180] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x01000000 | data2
[  475.842181] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[  475.842182] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0xCE0037D8 | beacon time
[  475.842184] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0xB1B167F6 | tsf low
[  475.842185] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x0000014D | tsf hi
[  475.842186] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[  475.842188] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x0B832069 | time gp2
[  475.842189] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[  475.842190] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000053 | uCode version major
[  475.842191] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0xEC13314B | uCode version minor
[  475.842193] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000472 | hw version
[  475.842194] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00C80002 | board version
[  475.842195] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x8000FC11 | hcmd
[  475.842196] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00020000 | isr0
[  475.842198] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[  475.842199] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x48F00002 | isr2
[  475.842200] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00C0000C | isr3
[  475.842201] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[  475.842202] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[  475.842204] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x002A50FC | wait_event
[  475.842205] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[  475.842206] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[  475.842207] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x003C0000 | l2p_mhvalid
[  475.842209] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000007 | l2p_addr_match
[  475.842210] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000028 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[  475.842211] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[  475.842212] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000860 | flow_handler
[  475.842446] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[  475.842448] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 7
[  475.842450] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[  475.842452] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[  475.842453] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0xC00809B0 | umac branchlink2
[  475.842454] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x802698E4 | umac interruptlink1
[  475.842455] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x01093000 | umac interruptlink2
[  475.842457] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x01000000 | umac data1
[  475.842458] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x01093000 | umac data2
[  475.842459] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[  475.842460] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000053 | umac major
[  475.842462] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0xEC13314B | umac minor
[  475.842463] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x0B83205E | frame pointer
[  475.842464] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0xD00D625C | stack pointer
[  475.842465] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x000A010C | last host cmd
[  475.842466] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000400 | isr status reg
[  475.842722] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: TCM1 status:
[  475.842725] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000070 | error ID
[  475.842726] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x0000184E | tcm branchlink2
[  475.842727] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00001C44 | tcm interruptlink1
[  475.842728] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00001C44 | tcm interruptlink2
[  475.842730] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x40000000 | tcm data1
[  475.842731] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | tcm data2
[  475.842732] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | tcm data3
[  475.842733] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x000018AC | tcm log PC
[  475.842734] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00803FF0 | tcm frame pointer
[  475.842735] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00803F4C | tcm stack pointer
[  475.842737] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | tcm msg ID
[  475.842738] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x4000000F | tcm ISR status
[  475.842739] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000EF3 | tcm HW status[0]
[  475.842740] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | tcm HW status[1]
[  475.842741] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00003C20 | tcm HW status[2]
[  475.842743] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x40008340 | tcm HW status[3]
[  475.842744] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000003 | tcm HW status[4]
[  475.842745] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | tcm SW status[0]
[  475.842987] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: RCM1 status:
[  475.842988] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000070 | error ID
[  475.842990] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00001B9E | rcm branchlink2
[  475.842991] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00002178 | rcm interruptlink1
[  475.842992] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00002178 | rcm interruptlink2
[  475.842993] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x20000000 | rcm data1
[  475.842994] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | rcm data2
[  475.842995] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | rcm data3
[  475.842996] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00001C00 | rcm log PC
[  475.842997] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00803FF0 | rcm frame pointer
[  475.842999] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00803F4C | rcm stack pointer
[  475.843000] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | rcm msg ID
[  475.843001] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x2004F000 | rcm ISR status
[  475.843002] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x3C5605CC | frame HW status
[  475.843003] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | LMAC-to-RCM request mbox
[  475.843004] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | RCM-to-LMAC request mbox
[  475.843005] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x000000B4 | MAC header control
[  475.843007] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0xC29A8AC8 | MAC header addr1 low
[  475.843008] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x01000050 | MAC header info
[  475.843009] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | MAC header error
[  475.843250] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: TCM2 status:
[  475.843252] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000070 | error ID
[  475.843253] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x0000184E | tcm branchlink2
[  475.843254] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00001C44 | tcm interruptlink1
[  475.843255] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00001C44 | tcm interruptlink2
[  475.843256] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x40000000 | tcm data1
[  475.843257] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | tcm data2
[  475.843258] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | tcm data3
[  475.843259] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x000018AC | tcm log PC
[  475.843260] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00803FF0 | tcm frame pointer
[  475.843262] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00803F4C | tcm stack pointer
[  475.843263] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | tcm msg ID
[  475.843264] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x40000000 | tcm ISR status
[  475.843265] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x000002F0 | tcm HW status[0]
[  475.843266] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | tcm HW status[1]
[  475.843268] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | tcm HW status[2]
[  475.843269] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00008000 | tcm HW status[3]
[  475.843270] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | tcm HW status[4]
[  475.843271] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | tcm SW status[0]
[  475.843513] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: RCM2 status:
[  475.843515] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000070 | error ID
[  475.843516] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00001B9E | rcm branchlink2
[  475.843517] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00002178 | rcm interruptlink1
[  475.843518] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00002178 | rcm interruptlink2
[  475.843519] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x20000000 | rcm data1
[  475.843520] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | rcm data2
[  475.843521] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | rcm data3
[  475.843522] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00001C00 | rcm log PC
[  475.843523] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00803FF0 | rcm frame pointer
[  475.843525] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00803F4C | rcm stack pointer
[  475.843526] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | rcm msg ID
[  475.843527] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x20000000 | rcm ISR status
[  475.843528] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00020400 | frame HW status
[  475.843529] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | LMAC-to-RCM request mbox
[  475.843530] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | RCM-to-LMAC request mbox
[  475.843532] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | MAC header control
[  475.843533] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | MAC header addr1 low
[  475.843534] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x003C0000 | MAC header info
[  475.843535] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | MAC header error
[  475.843752] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[  475.843754] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[  475.843765] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x0000EF8E | IML/ROM data1
[  475.843774] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[  475.843781] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[  475.843786] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[  475.843791] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x80B00004 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[  475.843797] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00550000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[  475.843802] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x0000AA14 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[  475.843807] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x0000000F | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[  475.843813] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[  475.843818] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x02001910 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[  475.843823] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x02001910 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[  475.843828] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x02001910 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[  475.843836] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x02001910 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[  475.843845] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00001BEF | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[  475.843854] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[  475.843859] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00550000 | FSEQ_PREV_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[  475.843864] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00B00004 | FSEQ_WIFI_FSEQ_VERSION
[  475.843869] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x00B00004 | FSEQ_BT_FSEQ_VERSION
[  475.843875] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x000000BF | FSEQ_CLASS_TP_VERSION
[  475.843886] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: UMAC CURRENT PC: 0x8026935a
[  475.843892] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: LMAC1 CURRENT PC: 0xd0
[  475.843897] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: LMAC2 CURRENT PC: 0xd0
[  475.843903] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: UMAC CURRENT PC 1: 0x80269358
[  475.843909] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: TCM1 CURRENT PC: 0xd0
[  475.843914] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: RCM1 CURRENT PC: 0xd0
[  475.843919] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: RCM2 CURRENT PC: 0xd0
[  475.843926] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: Function Scratch status:
[  475.843927] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: 0x01010100 | Func Scratch
[  475.987251] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
[  559.651877] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[  560.013390] iwlwifi 0000:55:00.0: Failed to send recovery cmd blob was invalid 1

Any suggestion ?
Your help would be greatly appreciated :)
